# How can I isolate the first character of each word in a string?

Tags: python

I wrote this program, but it doesn't work because, I cannot figure out what it is doing when i input two words seperated by a space

```
sinput = input("Enter a sentence") #Collects a string from the user
x = len(sinput) #Calculates how many characters there are in the string


for n in range(x):
    n = 0 #Sets n to 0
    lsinput = sinput.split(" ") #Splits sinput into seperate words
    lsinput = lsinput[n] #Targets the nth word and isolates it into the variable lsinput
    print(lsinput[1]) #Prints the 1st letter of lsinput
    n += 1 #Adds 1 to n so the loop can move on to the next word
```

Comment: You're modifying the iterator inside it, give it a different variable name

Answer (score 1):

i recommend starting with a beginner's book on python. not sure what. but definitely do some reading.

to answer your question to help get you going though, you can just do this:

```
[w[0] for w in sinput.split() if w]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you:

- set n back to 0 at every loop
- you looped over the wrong amount of iterations
- you used 1 to retrieve the first letter rather than 0 (indexes start at 0)

Adjusting this for your code:

```
sinput = input("Enter a string to convert to phonetic alphabet") #Collects a string from the user

lsinput = sinput.split(" ") #Splits sinput into seperate words
x = len(lsinput) #Calculates how many characters there are in the string

n = 0 #Sets n to 0

for n in range(x):
    print(lsinput[n][0]) #Prints the 1st letter of the nth word in 5lsinput
    n += 1 #Adds 1 to n so the loop can move on to the next word
```

I also moved lsinput forward so that you don't recalculate this list with every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i really understood the question, but if you want to get all the first letters of each word in the input this code will do it

```
map(lambda x: x[0], sinput.split(" "))
```